# Grails validation rejectValue error

Tags: grails, validation

I'm using a service to validate quite a complex command object ..

In one of my tests / validations I have ..

```
if (!txn.documentHeader) {
        println "Received ${txn.documentReferenceCode}"
        errors.rejectValue('documentReferenceCode', "document.not.found",
                [txn.documentReferenceCode].toArray(), 'Document not found')
        println "Recorded ${errors.getFieldError('documentReferenceCode').rejectedValue}"
} else {  ...
```

When I test this I get ..

```
Received  NOT EXIST
Recorded  NOT EXIST
```

which is correct ..

I have a similar test (I can see no difference) in another service ..

```
println "Received ${txn.fromTag.documentHeader.documentReferenceCode}"
         errors.rejectValue('fromTagCode', "tag.document.state.error",
         [txn.fromTag.documentHeader.documentReferenceCode].toArray(),
         'Document not in correct state')
println "Recorded ${errors.getFieldError('fromTagCode').rejectedValue}"
```

When I test produces  ..

```
Received Fault
Recorded null
```

.. I'm loosing the rejected value - and my test is failing  .. Anyone any idea  ????

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My bad .. the recorded rejected value is the content value of the rejected field (field 'fromTag') and NOT the value passed to the rejectValue as the parameter which ends up on the screen (txn.fromTag.documentHeader.documentReferenceCode) .. So everything is okay !!